# actix-web: How to create a route like this: /starts-with/a/b/c/d/.../e?

Tags: rust, actix-web

```
#[get("/starts-with/{other_url}")]
async fn t1(other_url: web::Path<String>) -> impl Responder {
    other_url.to_string()
}
```

This handler works for /starts-with/a, but it doesn't work for /starts-with/a/b.

How can I create a route which works with an arbitrary number of slashes?

Comment: I would try `Path` from `std::path`. So `other_url: web::Path<std::path::Path>`. I have no idea whether it will work though. (Don't know anything about actix-web and didn't look it up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67039276/resource-regex-cause-panic) and [actix doc](https://actix.rs/docs/url-dispatch/) you could use the regex pattern match like

```rust
#[get("/starts-with/{other_url:.*}")]
async fn t1(other_url: web::Path<String>) -> impl Responder {
    other_url.to_string()
}
```

```bash
➜ curl http://127.0.0.1:8081/starts-with/x/y
Path("x/y")%
➜ curl http://127.0.0.1:8081/starts-with/x
Path("x")%
➜ curl http://127.0.0.1:8081/starts-with/x/y/z
Path("x/y/z")%
```

but this will require further parsing of the string.