# How to match `/foo.*` prefix in Actix?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I would like to handle these cases in Actix:

- `/foo`
- `/foo/`
- `/foo/.*` (anything including slashes)

Note that `foo` is a constant string, and I do not need to actually parse the path. Instead, in my handler I will

```rust
pub async fn on_foo(
    client: web::Data<reqwest::Client>,
    req: HttpRequest,
    mut payload: web::Payload,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
...
  // Use client to fully forward any /foo... requests elsewhere
  // using req.path() to get the full original path.
}
```

It seems one option is to use scopes:

```rust
.service(
    actix_web::web::scope("/foo").default_service(actix_web::web::to(on_foo))
),
```

But this method doesn't seem to handle `/foo/` (while it does look like it handles the other two cases)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [actix-web: How to create a route like this: /starts-with/a/b/c/d/.../e?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72700142/actix-web-how-to-create-a-route-like-this-starts-with-a-b-c-d-e)

Comment: thx, but not exactly. That question deals with sub-paths, whereas my question is about the declared path (all 3 cases)